# how to do regular expression pattern matching expression in perl

Tags: perl

I am reading line from the file :

```
CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE GPRS - Intl Roaming - Mexico - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)|12920|MB|7750|1000|(243)
```

I use the below logic

```
$line=~m/^(CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS).*?\s(.*?)\|.*\|(.*?)\s
```

I am able to extract the data separately like below

```
print"
Tag:CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS,
amt:1000,
lineTxt:GPRS - Intl Roaming - Mexico - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)\n";
```

How to extract another item called `$usage = 12920`?

Comment: Stick another capture bracket in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to adapt your regular expression, you can add another capture group inside. I suggest to be a bit more specific and use `\d` instead of `.` to match numbers only.

```
/^(CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS).*?\s(.*?)\|(\d+)\|.*\|(.*?)\s/
```

The `12920` will end up in `$3` and `(243)` will now be `$4`.

---

<sub>Note that you're not actually capturing the `CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE` from your example data. The `_SIMPLE` is lost. You are also not outputting the number in parenthesis `(243)`. Did you make a mistake when copying your code into the question?</sub>

---

However it's probably better to use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). If the data has the same format in every line, it might look like the following. Of course I had to make some guesses here as the question is rather vauge.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my ($first_part, @details) = split /\|/, $line;
  my ($tag, $line_txt) = split /\s/, $first_part, 2;

  say "Tag: $tag";
  say "amt: $details[3]";
  say "lineTxt: $line_txt";
  say "usage: $details[0]";
}

__DATA__
CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE GPRS - Intl Roaming - Mexico - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)|12920|MB|7750|1000|(243)
```